# Pentaho + MYSQL Initialization Exception

Tags: mysql, pentaho, saiku

I have the same problem

```
Pentaho Initialization Exception

The following errors were detected One or more system listeners failed.
These are set in the systemListeners.xml.
org.pentaho.platform.api.engine.PentahoSystemException: 
PentahoSystem.ERROR_0014 - Error while trying to execute startup 
sequence for org.pentaho.platform.scheduler2.
quartz.EmbeddedQuartzSystemListener
```

Please go through the logs :

The Catalina log https://www.dropbox.com/s/knpuu6nazwa8p0g/catalina.out?dl=0

The Pentaho log file https://www.dropbox.com/s/fz99afs9ov0pnfs/pentaho.log?dl=0

Followed tutorial : https://interestingittips.wordpress.com/2011/05/05/complete-pentaho-installation-on-ubuntu-part-2/

Please help me! Thanks in advance

Comment: Follow this link - http://infocenter.pentaho.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fconfig_ba_server%2Ftask_starting_ba_server.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By going through your logs, both catalina.out and pentaho log have the same issue written. I think you have to check your DB connections.

> Failure occured during job recovery. [See nested exception:
>   org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Failed to obtain DB connection
>   from data source 'myDS': java.sql.SQLException: There is no DataSource
>   named 'myDS' [See nested exception: java.sql.SQLException: There is no
>   DataSource named 'myDS']]